# Private Route React Router And Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am trying to build a simple React app with auth flow and private route, I am first checking if the user signed in and redirect it to specify a private route, but after the app goes to the private route she doesn't have the user info  here is my code :

App.Js

```
class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
}

render() {
console.log('AUTH:' , this.props.signedIn);
return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to={this.props.signedIn ? '/dashboard' : '/login'}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" ><DashboardLayout/></PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
  }
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    signedIn: state.auth.signedIn
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchUser: () => dispatch(fetchUser())
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({children, signedIn, ...rest}) => {


const checkToken = (location) => {

    console.log("SignedIn", signedIn);
    if(signedIn) {
        return children;
    }
    else {
        return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from : location}}}/>
    }

};

return <Route
    {...rest}
    render={({location}) => checkToken(location)}
/>;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    signedIn: state.auth.signedIn
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute)
```

So, in my google console, I see my console log AUTH is set to false from the App.js and also my console log Signed In is set to false, but after a rerender my console log AUTH from the app is set to True but doesn't go to the PrivateRoute again
[image: Google Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use 3 returns for PrivateRoute

- children - for authorized users
- Redirect to login - for not authorized users
- and some LoadingComponent - for waiting of fetching user

We've prepared list of Loading components with different structure of placeholders, they look like placeholders in youtube on page loading

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({children, signedIn, isAuthReady, customPlaceholder, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(location) => {
      if (!isAuthReady) {
        return customPlaceholder || <Placeholder /> 
      }

      if (signedIn) {
        return children;
      }

      return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from : location}}} />
    }} />
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  signedIn: state.auth.signedIn,
  isAuthReady: state.auth.isAuthReady
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)
```